# How to assign custom external/public IP for Kubernetes v1.2 Ingress resource on GKE?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have followed the instructions (https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer, and http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) to create an Ingress resource for my Kubernetes Service - my cluster is deployed within Google Container Engine (GKE).

I understand that the Ingress controller will automatically allocate an external/public IP for me, but this is not exactly what I need. Am I able to decide what IP I want? I have a domain name and a static IP which I would like to use instead of the one assigned by the Ingress controller.

Hopefully this can be defined inside the json/yaml configuration file for the Ingress resource. This is my preferred way to create resources as I can keep track of the state of the created resources (rather than using `kubectl edit` from command line to edit my way to the preferred state).

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/pull/1852/commits/7123c70ff94040ed7f67f4a2d050c4240cb5f781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the Ingress controller will automatically allocate an external/public IP for me, but this is not exactly what I need. Am I able to decide what IP I want?

You can ask Google for a static global IP address, which can then be used for your L7 load balancing (you would point your DNS name to this IP). There isn't a way to bring your own IP address into a google L7 load balancer (either directly or using the Ingress object).

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question.  How does one specify the IP reserved with google in the ingress definition?

Comment: The question was how to use an IP address that you already owned into google's cloud (which isn't possible). Asking how to use an IP addresses reserved from google in an ingress object is a different question.

Comment: @RobertBailey Hm in the case that I have a static IP reserved through google cloud, how can I specify within the Ingress config to use that particular IP?

Comment: I don't see a field in the ingress specification to add a pre-reserved ip address. But you can configure the google HTTP(S) load balancer manually with the reserved static IP.

Comment: @RobertBailey Ok thanks a lot for the info! We are looking towards a dynamic DNS solution instead that can handle dynamic IP mappings to our subdomain (with the Dynamic IP being the Load Balancer's IP).

Comment: As mentioned in a top-level comment, the GLB ingress controller has now added support for selecting an existing static IP address by way of an annotation: `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: 'my-ip-address-name'`

You will need to create the static IP address directly through the GCP dashboard (or `gcloud` util). If you already have an ingress with a dynamic IP address that you want to preserve, you should be able to convert it to static in place, and then add the annotation.